# How to insert array elements as sub array like first element is the parent of second,second is the parent of third and so on?

Tags: php, arrays, sub-array

I need to convert an array that is like 
  `$data = array('Image','Thumbnail','size')`  to 
     `$data= array('Image'=>array('Thumbnail'=>array('size'=>'test')));` format.
How it will be possible?.
I had tried something like below.

```
$count= count($data);
$last = $count-1;
for($i=$count-2;$i>=0;$i--)
{
  $newArray[$data[$i]][$data[$last]]='test'; 
  $last=$i;

}
```

but it gives output as

```
Array(
[thumbnail] => Array
    (
        [type] => test
    )

[image] => Array
    (
        [thumbnail] => test
    ))
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you :-)

Comment: start from the top! then put every entry in it's array, save it and put it into next (=previous) item.

Comment: I didn't get you :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have other further considerations?

The following code is simply to do so:

```
<?php
$data = array('Image','Thumbnail','size');
$newArray[$data[0]][$data[1]][$data[2]]='test'; 
var_dump($newArray);
```

Or you could use for loop like this:

```
<?php
$data = array('Image','Thumbnail','size');
$result=array();
for($i=(count($data)-1);$i>=0;$i--){
    if($i==(count($data)-1))
        $result[$data[$i]]='test';
    else{
        $result[$data[$i]]=$result;
        unset($result[$data[$i+1]]);
    }
}
```

Comment: they want dynamic not static to pass keys

Comment: Yes. We could easily use this to generate dynamic code.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own method to create such a structure by just traversing the array and creating an inner child for each element.

```
function createPath($array) {
    $result = [];
    $current = &$result;
    foreach ($array as $node) {
        $current[$node] = [];
        $current = &$current[$node];
    }
    return $result;
}
```

This can also be done with `array_reduce` and an reversed array: ([array_reduce doumentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php), [array_reverse documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php))

```
$result = array_reduce(array_reverse($array), function($carry, $element) {
       return [$element => $carry]; 
    }, []);
```

While the `foreach` solution will build the structure from the outer element to the most inner element, the `array_reduce` solution will build it from the inner to the outer elements.

Both solutions will create the output:

```
[
    'Image' => [
        'Thumbnail' => [
            'size' => []
        ]
    ]
]
```

If you want the most inner key to contain another value than an empty array, you can change the intial value of the `array_reduce` carry to that desired value or add another parameter to the `createPath` function, that adds this value as the most inner key.

Comment: The first solution doesn't work. But the second solution does work and seems so magic!

Comment: @Phil Thanks for the hint. I forgot the reference operator in the first solution, which i added now. It works now. [running example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/46a9dec4250c459a28d5ed58f80ac209008e944a)

Comment: Great job! Learn lot from this.

Comment: First solution seems to be not working but the second one is great. Thank you so much for your help @Philipp Maurer :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this, with very basic logic:

```
$array = array('Image','Thumbnail','size', 'test');
$a = [];
$i = count($array)- 1;
$a[$array[$i-1]] = $array[$i];
--$i;
while($i >= 1 ) {
    $a[$array[$i-1]] = $a;
    unset($a[$array[$i]]);
    --$i;
}
```

Comment: Your code would be simpler with a `do{}while()` loop and a the condition `$i > 0` in it.

Comment: unset() is not required for the first time. so using do while will not help.

Comment: I thought about `do {
    $a = [$array[--$i] => $a];
} while($i > 0);`, which is nearly equivalent to your code.